# Add a new select field with having

Tags: mysql

It is a mysql question.
Here is a simple table which needs to be groupped by groupid.(just madeup,has no purpose except the solution to the problem)

```
id car  house  pets   groupid
1   1     2    1        1
1   0     1    0        1
1   0     0    0        1
```

```
SELECT SUM(car),SUM(house),SUM(pets) FROM table GROUP BY id
```

So the result is

```
car 1 house 3 pets 1
```

What im trying to do is to insert a new selected field to the group 'any_record_with_all_zeros' which is 0 if the group has a row where car=0 house=0 pets=0

So the desired result would be

```
car 1,house 3, pets 1, any_record_with_all_zeros = 1
```

If the id 3 row's any field would be other than 0, than the 'any_record_with_all_zeros is 0'

I know im supposed to go with HAVING, but i dont know how to put the 'any_record...' field to the SELECT part.

```
SELECT 
 SUM(car),SUM(house),SUM(pets),any_record_with_all_zeros
FROM 
 table
GROUP BY
 groupid
HAVING if car=0 && house=0 && pets=0 than any_record_with_all_zeros = 0 or something similar
```

Any idea?

Comment: "So the result is `car 1 house 3 pets 1`" - Are you sure? Please check your `id` values in the table.

Comment: The result doesn’t match the group by, it would match sums with no grouping. Also HAVING won’t help in getting that information, you could use a SUM with a CASE

Comment: Yeah your are right. lets assume id is all 1 :). the point is to find a row where all fields are 0 and make a new field with 0

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: the question is to mark somehow the groupped result with 0, if any row of that group has cat and house and pets all 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing the NOT of a couple of [Bitwise OR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html) also works.

> ```
> create table `table` (
>  id int primary key auto_increment, 
>  groupid int not null, 
>  car int not null default 0,
>  house int not null default 0,
>  pet int not null default 0
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into `table` (groupid, car, house, pet) values
>  (1, 1, 2, 1)
> ,(1, 0, 1, 0)
> ,(1, 0, 0, 0)
> -- ,(1, 0, 0, 0)
> -- ,(1, 0, 0, 0)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> groupid, 
> SUM(car) as cars, 
> SUM(house) as houses, 
> SUM(pet) as pets, 
> SUM(not(car | house | pet)) as none
> FROM `table`
> GROUP BY groupid
> ```
>
> ```
> groupid | cars | houses | pets | none
> ------: | ---: | -----: | ---: | ---:
>       1 |    1 |      3 |    1 |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=152f865cb9b1ad7d5664b7772f9e91ac)*

Comment: Thank you Luk.This will do it.

Comment: @Ninet9 Thx. And you can even golf-code it. I.e. `SUM(!(car|house|pet))`.  But with a `NOT` it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for car + house + pets

```
SELECT 
 SUM(car)
 ,SUM(house)
 ,SUM(pets)
 , sum (case when (car + house + pets)  = 0 then 1 else 0 end) any_record_with_all_zeros
FROM   table
GROUP BY groupid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`BIT_OR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or) aggregate function. If any of the set values from the group ist TRUE, BIT_OR will also return TRUE.

```
SELECT groupid
  , SUM(car)
  , SUM(house)
  , SUM(pets)
  , BIT_OR((car, house, pets) = (0, 0, 0)) as any_record_with_all_zeros
FROM `table`
GROUP BY groupid
```

Comment: "The SELECT area can only see the groupped values not individuals" - `BIT_OR` is an aggregate function like SUM or MAX or COUNT.